# Is there a method in gitlab to list all projects where default branch is behind?

Tags: gitlab, project

I would like to be able to have a list of all projects where the default branch is at least one commit behind another branch.

Ideally a list of all projects that have a branch called "staging" and the default branch (usually "master") is behind.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up writing a [Commandbox](https://commandbox.ortusbooks.com/) task runner to accomplish the task.

It took some time working through the gitlab API documentation to get this working, and there may be a better way, but this works well enough.

I've created a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/l8nites/9181a12c25fe50f66120d999a2df1435).

Answer (score 0):

Using gitlab ee, you can use [multi project pipeline](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/multi_project_pipelines.html) giving a specific variable so it only runs a specific job on every given project.

You could then see if jobs are failing or successful from the ci view (and then know the wanted state for each project)